# Why in the output characteristic graph of BJTs, within the saturation region, is the collector current positive?

Tags: diodes, bjt, semiconductors, junction

It is known that in the saturation region of the BJTs the pn junction is reverse biased. The reason for being reversed biased could be explained as follow:
**V**ce=**V**cb+**V**be
Therefore
**V**cb=**V**ce-**V**be
We can see that if the **V**ce<**V**be (saturation region) then **V**cb would be negative, which means **V**c<**V**b and therefore the base-collector junction is forward biased.
Since we consider positive direction of collector's current while the base-collector junction is reversed biased, in case of forward-biasing we need to consider the current in opposite direction (negative).

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the graph in your question is wrong?

Comment: You should cite where that graphic comes from.  I have problems with the 0.7V saturation region and linear breakdown region.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior in the deep saturation region is not correctly shown in that diagram.

Here is a simulation for Ib = 10mA, 0 < Vc < 100mV and a 2N4401:

[image]

If the collector voltage is less than about 20mV the net current flow is out of the collector.

Note also that at Vc = 0, the *majority* of the base current flows out of the collector rather than the emitter. This is a hint as to how you can usually identify collector from emitter on an unknown transistor.